# Как я могу реализовать визуализацию разграничения объекта SVG с закругленными уголками

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, градиент

Я хочу, чтобы реализовать визуализацию объекта SVG, который разделяется несколькими цветами.

Вроде как то так, этот фрагмент HTML+CSS воспроизводит.

```css
#wholeThing {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wholeThing div {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#foo {
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
}

#bar {
  background: green;
  width: 10px;
}

#baz {
  background: blue;
  width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wholeThing'>
  <div id='foo'></div>
  <div id='bar'></div>
  <div id='baz'></div>
  <div id='quux'></div>
</div>
```

Это должно быть реализовано в SVG, потому что визуализация будет добавлена к другим элементам SVG, и я не хочу использовать тэг `foreignobject`.

Я пробовал вставлять более мелкие прямоугольники в один SVG элемент, например:

```
 <svg>
  <rect> ...
  <rect> ...
  <rect> ...
</svg>
```

Но я не вижу, как я могу реализовать закругленные углы с таким подходом. Один закругленный угол может охватывать несколько небольших прямоугольников, как в моем примере.

Кроме того, SVG элемент не воспринимает `border-radius` свойство `CSS`.
Может быть, я мог бы сделать эту визуализацию, используя разноцветные обводки линии?

Источник: [How could I implement a divided bar visualization in SVG with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127554/how-could-i-implement-a-divided-bar-visualization-in-svg-with-rounded-corners/42127683#42127683)

Comment: Поправте ссылку в ассоциации, она ведёт на ответ, а не на вопрос.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/42127554/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов, как вы можете сделать это:

- используя - `<clipPath>`
- используя - `<mask>`
- используя - `<linearGradient>`

Например, с использованием градиента:

```html
 <svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="graph1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="green"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="50" rx="10" ry="10" fill="url(#graph1)"/>
</svg>
```

Ответил - [@PaulLeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42127683/6571020)